# GraphQL subscription: How to update object based on the event in subscription

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I am trying to update the users' password that I have retrieved previously when an event is published to the `PasswordUpdated` Channel. This is what I have tried so far,

```
this.apollo.subscribe({
  query: this.passwordUpdatedSubscription
}).subscribe(({passwordUpdated}:any) => {
  this.userDataQuery.updateQuery((previousResult) => {
    previousResult.getUsers.filter(user => user.name === passwordUpdated.name).forEach(user => user.password = passwordUpdated.password);
  });

});
```

However, I just found out from the error in the console that `previousResult` is immutable. When I tried to update the password in `previousResult`, the property has `writable: false`. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the changed previous result. Check out [subscription docu](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/subscriptions.html#subscribe-to-more) for apollo client. A bit below is the point for the update query.

And you might want to check [reacts immutability helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) which explains a little bit what the problem is.

Comment: The `SubscribeToMore` function is available to the apollo-react client only. Unfortunately it is not available for the angular client. I checked the updateQuery from that page, it looks like they are re-creating the `newComments` array and push the new comments to it, which is what I am trying to avoid. I am looking for a way to mutate the previous result, rather than re-creating a new result from previous result.

Comment: You are right. I did not find `SubscribeToMore`. One thing that you could check if it is possible that the apollo client for angular does it for you in the background with `dataIdFromObject` [docu](http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/cache-updates.html#dataIdFromObject). It should update the apollo store when youre response contains the id of the user.